# How can I add strong parameters to my controller using a concern file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters, activesupport-concern

How can I **add strong parameters** to my controller **using a concern file?**

Lets say I have `:name, :age, :sex` parameters that are used by several controllers, my idea is to create a concern module where I store these `common_params` and add them to the permitted parameters as I'm vaguely trying to do here below.

Controller

```
class PersonController < ApplicationController
  include CommonHelper

  def update
    @person.create(person_params)
  end

  private 

    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:foo, :bar, common_params)
    end
end
```

Concern

```
module CommonHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def common_params
    { :name, :age, :sex }
  end
end
```

Ideally I should get the same result as if I was doing: `permit(:foo, :bar, :name, :age, :sex)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `*` operator, which splits the array into a parameter list and can be included as part of an existing parameter list:

```
params= ActionController::Parameters.new(person: {foo: 'something', bar: 'something else', name: 'Someone', age: 27, sex: 'M', random: 'not valid'})

# however you want to define and include these (method, constant, etc)
def common_params
  [:name, :age, :sex]
end

params.require(:person).permit(:foo, :bar, *common_params)
# => <ActionController::Parameters {"foo"=>"something", "bar"=>"something else", "name"=>"Someone", "age"=>27, "sex"=>"M"} permitted: true>
```

Comment: Apparently adding `*common_params` at the end is not right. I get error 500 and in my log it says `syntax error, unexpected *, expecting ')'`. This doesn't happen if it's the first argument of permit.

Comment: Weird, had all your commas in a row? I mean it's clearly working in the example here..front of list vs back of list ends up with the same output, that's just strange it didn't work for you

Comment: Found out. I had a nested param `foo: [:x, :y, :z]` and adding `*common_params` after generates the error. As long as it's before the nested it's fine. Not sure what's the problem though.

Comment: Ah makes sense, you didn't wrap that in the curlies, so the hash has to be the last thing in the parameter list in order to be like that...could've fixed it by doing `permit({foo: [:x, :y, :z]}, :bar, *common_params)` as well

Comment: That's it! Thank you @Simple Lime

Answer (score 0):

Concern

```
module CommonHelper
  COMMON_PARAMS = %i[ name age sex ].freeze
end
```

Controller

```
def person_params
  params
    .require(:person)
    .permit([:foo, :bar] | CommonHelper::COMMON_PARAMS)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2018:** 
***Rails: 5.2.0 & Ruby: 2.5.1***

Create a concern module like this:

`app/controllers/concerns/Xxxxx_helper.rb`

`module XxxxxHelper
  COMMON_STRONG_PARAMS = %i[ param1 param2 param3 ].freeze
end`

And in your controller do:

`def xxxxxx_params
  params.require(:xxxxxx).permit(:some_param :another_param, :another_param, :last_param, XxxxxHelper::COMMON_STRONG_PARAMS)
end`

This works!